# Send response in POST request

Tags: java, playframework

My route
`POST     /article/create   Application.create`

Application.java file

```
public static void create(Article article) {
   article.save();
  //send article ID (article.id) after saving
```

}

Is it possible to send article.id as a response to the client once the article has been saved in the DB? If yes, what is the best way to do it

Comment: Your URL should not contain the word `create` twice! In fact, it should contain it zero times. The fact that you are POSTing it is enough, in a REST API.

Comment: @RobinGreen - Surely it should contain it once, i.e. `POST /articles Application.create` (or even better `Article.create`) ?

Comment: @Flukey No, in a REST API you use `POST` to signify this - the "create" verb is implied, and doesn't need to be stated explicitly.

Comment: @RobinGreen Yes, but the POST request still needs to point to an action in the controller. The action could even be called 'post' but it still needs to be supplied in the routing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread it as a HTTP verb and an URL with an unencoded space, not a route specification.

Comment: No worries - this was why I was a bit confused by your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of play you are using, but if it's play2 your method signature looks like missing return type.

Please see more from here, and decide yourself how you want to return newly created id

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaResponse

You have several possibilities to return id

- headers
- body of response
- or even cookies

Inside body you can return just id, or embed id inside json, xml, html or some other data structure.

Comment: Also, you should consider using a `201 Created` HTTP response code.

Comment: Thanks @RobinGreen. So instead of returning response using ok (..) one can return it using created (..). API's here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#created()